# How to run a shell script on rpi3 that required GUI on boot?

Tags: pi-3, boot, script, bash, lxterminal

I used [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) page to try to run a shell script when the raspberry pi first turns on. This is the line I added at the bottom of the file(before `exit 0`):

```
sh /home/pi/alexa_start.sh &
```

I added the ampersand, as suggested by the webstie above, because my script is a continuous script that is supposed to start Amazon Alexa. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/pi
lxterminal -e sh ./alexa1.sh & sleep 3
lxterminal -e sh ./alexa2.sh & sleep 20
lxterminal -e sh ./alexa3.sh
lxterminal -e sh ./alexa4.sh
```

It runs 4 other scripts in separate terminal windows. Upon booting the pi, nothing happened. I tried using sudo in the rc.local file and it didn't help. Is the problem the `lxterminal`? How can I make this work?

EDIT:

I also tried adding this line `@lxterminal -e /home/pi/alexa_start.sh`
to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` as suggested [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=43509), but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

> The answer below doesn't take into account that `lxterminal` requires the GUI to be up and running to succeed

One problem is most likely the "current working directory"

When you start

```
sh /home/pi/alexa_start.sh &
```

The current working directory is `/` - as the `alexa?.sh` scripts are in `/home/pi`, it's clear that `./alexa?.sh` won't exist

edit `/home/pi/alexa_start.sh` as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/pi
lxterminal -e sh ./alexa1.sh & sleep 3
... etc
```

I assume `alexa?.sh` etc are in `/home/pi`

> Alternatively, add the `/home/pi` to the path of the script

```
#!/bin/sh
lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa1.sh & sleep 3
lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa2.sh & sleep 20
lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa3.sh
lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa4.sh
```

The difference between the two answers is what the current directory will be in the `alexa?.sh` scripts - in the first answer it will be `/home/pi` - in the second it will be whatever it was when `rc.local` ran the start script (again, most likely `/` - but I wouldn't count on anything at this point)

Note: in either case, the `alexa?.sh` scripts will be running as **root**. If the alexa scripts need to be run as a user other that root, say as user **pi** then change the command in `rc.local` to

```
su pi -c '/home/pi/alexa_start.sh &'
```

or even

```
su pi -l -c '/home/pi/alexa_start.sh &'
```

the `-l` would mean you don't need to make the path "changes" above, as this will be done for you. The `-l` argument *Provides an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly*

Comment: I added `cd /home/pi` to my alexa_start script and nothing happened. This is what my rc.local looks like now: `python3 /home/pi/shutdown.py &
sh /home/pi/alexa_start.sh &` When I booted the PI, I was brought to the GUI without any lxterminal windows open.

Comment: oh ... `lxterminal` relies on GUI being active ... that's yet another problem - you need to wait for the GUI to be running before running lxterminal

Comment: to wait for GUI, one method is to use `systemd` and create your script above as a service, that waits for `display-manager.service`

Answer (score 0):

Add this stuff to `/home/pi_h/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

```
@/usr/bin/lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa1.sh & sleep 3
@/usr/bin/lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa2.sh & sleep 20
@/usr/bin/lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa3.sh
@/usr/bin/lxterminal -e sh /home/pi/alexa4.sh
```

That `autostart` file gets run as soon as you login (or get auto logged in) to the GUI